# Concatenate text from React Hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have following hook:

```
const [textToFront, setTextToFront] = useState('');
```

When I call `setTextToFront` I see that old state was cleared, I want to implement simple thing, I just want to create one big String in the hook and display. How to store and add new coming state to old state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
setTextToFront(`${textToFront}${newAppendedText}`);
```